# Django Admin: Show list of models

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using `Django 1.8.8`.

I have a lot of models defined as such:

```
class MainModel(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(null=False, editable=True, default=20)
    dt_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True)

class MyModel1(MainModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, editable=False, max_length=50)

class MyModel2(MainModel, models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(null=False, editable=False, max_length=50)
```

My admin page is currently setup as such,

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('value', 'dt_modified')
    search_fields = ['value']
    date_hierarchy = 'dt_modified'

models = [MyModel1, MyModel2]
admin.site.register(models, MyModelAdmin)
```

I want to setup my admin page as follows:
Have one link on the top page`/admin`, "MainModels" which directs me to another page where I can select from a list of all derived models of `MyModel`, i.e. `[MyModel1, MyModel2, ....MyMoneyN]` which lets me edit the selected derived model. `MyModel#`.

The problem with the code above is it creates a top level link for each numbered model.

Answer (score 2):

You're really best off using something like [Grapelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli) or another custom admin replacement. You can set custom pages with different sets of models, adjust hidden / shown by default, etc. Trying to do this with vanilla admin is going to be problematic.

Here is an example of something close to what you want to do with grappelli

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from grappelli.dashboard import modules, Dashboard

class MyDashboard(Dashboard):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Dashboard.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        # append an app list module for "Applications"
        self.children.append(modules.AppList(
            title=_('Applications'),
            column=1,
            css_classes=('grp-collapse grp-closed',),
            collapsible=True,
            exclude=('django.contrib.*',),
        ))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Have a look at the [Grapelli](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard_setup.html) or [django-suit](http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/develop/configuration.html#id1) documentations for examples. But on a more general level, you should consider why you want to use admin applications for a use case in which [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) with [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/) seem to be the perfect fit.

Comment: A good suggestion / comment...but this isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need your own changelist to do this:

```
class MyChangeList(ChangeList):
    def url_for_result(self, result):
        link = your_function_to_create_link()
        return link
```

Then use your `Changelist` in `ModelAdmin`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return MyChangeList
```

Comment: What would go into `your_function_to_create_link()`?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. I suppose you are using Django admin and you want a link to derived model object. In that case it could be something like this: `reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (result._meta.app_label, result._meta.model_name))`. It would construct a correct url for each objects change view. `result` here is your object.

Comment: I made the changes and when I run, `makemigrations` it says no changes detected.

Comment: You did not change anything in your model, you need no migrations

Comment: On the top level `/admin` page, I still see 1 link for each model after I made your changes? perhaps I’m missing something.

Comment: yes, sorry, I am wrong on the link function creation. I work on Django 1.7 and it could be done this way. If you have a base class `MainModel` and derived models `MyModel1` and `MyModel2`, your `result` object will have `result.mymodel1` or `result.mymodel2` depending on what object it is. If you test those attributes. you can call reverse on `result.mymodel1` or `result.mymodel2`. If you have more questions about this, let me know